# How to measure the capabilities of a wall adapter?

Tags: power-supply, measurement

I purchased [this](http://dx.com/p/24v-1a-dual-rj45-port-wall-switching-poe-adapter-eu-plug-140097) from dx.com. The specs on the device claim 1A@24V.

The device exhibits 24V at no load on pins +4,5 and -7,8. According to Wikipedia, this is called a [passive power injector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_over_Ethernet#Passive). I tried drawing 1A from the device and failed (some protection drops the voltage to 0V).

How do I determine how much current can I draw from it? Are there some cheap variable resistor blocks or some other tricks?
[image]

Comment: Why close? Too localized? Please, give me some feedback.

Comment: @W5VO, thank you for your care of the question. However, protecting it removed the answer of a new user, user2020 I believe, that contained the interesting idea of dumping the power into the heatsink of a transistor. How do we bring it back (or you think it is a bad answer?)?

Comment: I'm sorry, this is an on-going moderation issue and I cannot restore that answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic answer is "try different loads to see what works and what doesn't".  All other answers are a variation on this.

Of course you can swap out different values of load resistors, measure what the voltage/current is with different resistors.  Then graph the results.  That's the "poor man's" way to do it, and it works surprisingly well.

On the other end of the "sophistication scale", there are electronic loads.  This is a box that looks a lot like a nice benchtop power supply, but provides a load.  You can configure this load in a variety of ways (Constant current, constant voltage, resistive, pulsing, etc.).   You change the load electronically and graph the result.

A third way is to make your own electronic load box.  Again, there are many ways to do this.  Simple relays that switch in/out load resistors works.  Or you can do the equivalent of a high-wattage current mirror (or amplifying current mirror).  An opamp plus MOSFET or Bipolar transistor can be turned into a regulated load.

All three of these options are valid.  But I can tell you this:  most people use the first approach, just sticking on some load resistors.  If people get fancy then they add some switches and a heat-sink to the resistors.  Cheap, simple, and adaptable.

One thing to keep in mind with any of this:  It is likely (70% ?)that some sort of Polyfuse is being used to limit the current.  This is basically a resistor that dramatically increases it's resistance when it gets hot.  Run a lot of current through the device and it heats up, thus increasing the resistance.  When the temperature goes down, the resistance goes back down.  These are used as self-resetting fuses.  The problem with these is that they are not terribly accurate, and their operation depends on the ambient temperature.  So on a hot day they might kick in at a lower current than on a cold day.  Keep that in mind when figuring out how much current your wall adapter can support.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't happen to own a handful of 24W resistors :(

Comment: @Vorac  Having a bunch of power resistors on hand is a good idea.  Plus some alligator test leads to hook them up (Note:  these have a not insignificant resistance to them).  In the grand scheme of things, getting some resistors is often easier and cheaper to do than dealing with the other alternatives.

Comment: @Vorac, you don't have to use 24W resistors one at a time, you can string 5W resistors in series, five or more of them, or 30 x 1W resistors if that's what you have on hand.

Comment: Turns out the current limit is really quite erratic - this time it cut off somewhere ABOVE 1.8A.

Answer (score 1):

Since it appears that the device is protected against loads that try to draw 1A, you know that there is an upper bound on its performance somewhere below that load, and that it is not destroyed by the attempt. So you can cheerfully probe the device with various smaller loads and plot voltage versus current on a graph.

Yes, there exist high wattage / low resistance variable resistors with sliding potentiometer taps for this sort of load testing.

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKkfhA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This was my test circuit, as I found it rather hard to get large resistors. [Here](http://club.dx.com/reviews/text/140097) is the review of the product.

Basically, I am vary happy with the purchase:

- $5.67 (if ordered ten units)
- 24V 1A
- 0.5Vpp noise at full load
- RJ-45 jack
- Over-current protection (not very accurate, rather a short-circuit protection)

Thanks to everyone for the advices!

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answers above, the best way to test this quickly and easily is to use an electronic load. Here you can specify how much you will draw from the device, and so you can quickly test to see whether it is drawing that much. It will work for extended periods.

EEVBLOG had some great video about testing a power supply that failed after being subjected to its maximum limits (it had a design flaw). Can't seem to find that video now.